Unable to use Astro Image Component with Astro DB that store the Links to them
So, i am trying to use AstroJs's Image Component to Display Optimized images on the Page.
i have put my images in the Project / src / images directory.
the only way to Provide a Link to the image is using this approach
Project / pages / index.astro
---
import { Image } from 'astro:assets';
import myImage from '../images/image.webp'
---

<Image src={myImage} alt="" .. />

if you try to give it the string path, this error welcome you
Project / pages / index.astro
---
import { Image } from 'astro:assets';
---

<Image src="../images/image.webp" alt="" .. />

Image's and getImage's src parameter must be an imported image or an URL, it cannot be a string filepath
my problem Start when i Try to store the link path to local Images stored in the Project / src / images to a db in order to fetch the link from remote Astro DB Server then use that image link path to locate images from local storage
i am not sure on what to store as a link that is represnted in string so that i can store it in a DB
What am trying to store here is Simple Services Table which has a title, description, img_src
i really have not had any idea to try
